# How to submit login form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I have a login form. When users press login, the jQuery checks if the fields are empty.  If they are not empty id like to submit my form to a page called `login_action.php`. I am unsure how to do this.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').click(function() {
        if(!$(':text').val()) {
            $('#errors').text('enter a username and password');
        } else {
            // This is where I'd like to redirect
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just submit the form:

```
$('#yourformsid').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you should set attributes `action='login_action.php'` and `id='myFormId'` to the form tag, and then modify your code as:

```
     <script type='text/javascript'>
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#login').click(function(){
                  if (!$(':text').val()){
                      $('#errors').text('enter a username and password');
                  } else {
                      //this is where i'd like to redirect
                      $("#myFormId").submit();
                  }
              });
          });
     </script>
```

PS: the `#login` button must not be type of `submit` but `button`. or if it is `submit`, you should add `return false;` if you don't want redirect and `return true;` it will post/get the form to the address that you've set in `action` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```

read more here:
http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Comment: this does not send the values (username/password) to the target page.

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann - the OP did ask how to "redirect".  That term doesn't mean send the login values - it means to go to a new page.  Perhaps the OP used the wrong term, but Landon was answering the question was asked.

Comment: i used the wrong term. sorry.  the submitting the form was the perfect solution

Comment: yeah, this is how you redirect. he didn't say he wanted to POST the form. but to be honest, i would presume he wants to submit the form

Comment: @jfriend00 correct. But what the OP actually asked does not solve the problem it is trying to solve. Eventhough the question was about how to "redirect", doing so does not solve anything.